# Location of Ansible playbook when running in Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure, xaml, ansible, azure-cloud-shell

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/getting-started-cloud-shell?tabs=ansible#create-an-azure-resource-group) official document `Quickstart: Configure Ansible using Azure Cloud Shell` from MS Azure site, asks you to first save the following code as `create_rg.yml`, and then run the `ansible-playbook` command (shown in second code block below) in Azure Cloud shell.

**Question**: Where do you save the `create_rg.yml` before running the command (shown in second code block below)?

**create_rg.yml file**:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Creating resource group - "{{ name }}"
      azure_rm_resourcegroup:
        name: "{{ name }}"
        location: "{{ location }}"
      register: rg
    - debug:
        var: rg
```

**ansible-playbook command to run the Azure Cloud Shell**:

```
ansible-playbook create_rg.yml --extra-vars "name=<resource_group_name> location=<resource_group_location>"
```

**Remark**: When I save create_rg.yml file in my local folder as `C:\TestFolder\create_rg.yml` the above command give the following error:

> > ERROR! the playbook: C:\TestFolder\create_rg.yml could not be found

Comment: Check fhe file permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the `.yml` file into your directory `/home/nancy` in the PowerShell or [Bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/quickstart) in Azure Cloud Shell instead of your local folder. There is a built-in ansible [tool in Azure cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/features).

[image]

Comment: I have another issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64564821/1232087) if you have time to comment/suggest a solution.