# Why Azure Cloud Shell is creating resource group in default subscription?

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-cloud-shell

I changed the subscription of the current session in `Azure Cloud Shell` to a different subscription using [Set-AzContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext?view=azps-5.0.0) as follows. But when I create a `Resource Group` using [Ansible playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html) in the same session of Azure Cloud Shell, the resource group is still created in default subscription, why?

```
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "myOtherSubscription"
```

Above command successfully changed the subscription from default to `myOtherSubscription` and showed the result as follows:

```
Name                                     Account                         SubscriptionName                Environment                     TenantId
----                                     -------                         ----------------                -----------                     --------
Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN (a86c7y8… MSI@51342                       Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN  AzureCloud                      86eafd5a-8ce3-4d0c-981c-8dac1…
```

Then I ran the the ansible command `ansible-playbook myplaybook_to_create_rg.yml` that successfully created the resource group but still in the default subscription instead of inside `myOtherSubscription`. As shown in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/getting-started-cloud-shell?tabs=ansible#create-an-azure-resource-group) example from Microsoft team there is no subscription mentioned in the ansible code for creating a resource group. That means it should create the resource group in the subscription that the Azure Cloud Shell in running on.

Comment: What's the value of your `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` environment variable (PowerShell: `$env:AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`)? Is it the ID of `myOtherSubscription` or another subscription? It's specifically mentioned in the linked article that the Ansible playbook uses that to determine which subscription to use: "*When working with multiple subscriptions, specify the subscription Ansible uses by exporting the `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` environment variable.*"

Comment: @esqew I think you got it. As explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/getting-started-cloud-shell?tabs=ansible#automatic-credential-configuration) I first need to run `export AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=<your-subscription-id>` with `my-subscription-id`. Let me try it first.

Comment: @esqew No. It still created the resource group inside default subscription. How do I check the value of `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` in the current session of Azure Cloud Shell?

Comment: The answer to your follow up will depend solely on the shell type you selected when setting up your Cloud Shell. As I mentioned before, for PowerShell-based Cloud Shells you can run a simple `$env:AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` to print the current value; in Bash-based shells you should be able to use something like `echo $AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`.

Comment: @esqew Huuum!!!. I'm using PowerShell-based. But `$env:AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` does not print the result. It just takes you back to the home prompt `PS /home/myAccountName>`

Comment: Can you explicitly set `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` in Cloud Shell as you mentioned before, then try to print it to the console again? If it still doesn’t print you may want to file a support ticket with the Azure team, as to my knowledge that isn’t standard PowerShell behavior.

Comment: @esqew Still doing the same thing. Time to file a support ticket with the Azure team. I'll do that.

Comment: Can you try one more thing? It's been a while since I've used PowerShell intensively for tasks relating to environment variables, and I just now looked up the proper syntax for exporting environment variables. Can you try to simply run `$env:AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="<your-subscription-id>"` to create the locally-scoped environment variable and re-run the Ansible playbook in the Cloud Shell? The issue may be that you're attempting to use `export` which isn't valid in a PowerShell-based environment. You should have gotten a big red error when trying to run the `export...` command.

Comment: @esqew You made it work (thank you). You may want to write your comment as a `Response` and I'll mark it as `Accepted` so some other readers can benefit from your response, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misunderstanding here is rooted in the fact that Ansible is *not* aware of the subscription selected as part of the `AzContext` you're working with. The documentation you linked corroborates this:

> When working with multiple subscriptions, specify the subscription Ansible uses by exporting the `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` environment variable.

For Cloud Shell, there are one of two ways to set which subscription Ansible uses dependent on your shell type:

- For **PowerShell** based Cloud Shell instances, set the `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` environment variable in the local scope by running:

  ```
  $env:AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="<your-subscription-id>"
  ```

  ... replacing the `<your-subscription-id>` placeholder with the target Azure subscription ID.
- For **`bash`**-based Cloud Shells, you can use the `export` keyword to achieve the same thing:

  ```
  export AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="<your-subscription-id>"`
  ```

  ... replacing the `<your-subscription-id>` placeholder with the target Azure subscription ID.